# Issues with Keras load_model function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN in Keras using a Tensorflow backend for speaker identification, and currently I am attempting to train the model and then save it in as an `.hdf5` file. The program trains the model for 100 epochs with early stopping and checkpoints, saving only the best model to a file, as illustrated in the code below:

```
class BuildModel:

    # Create First Model in Ensemble
    def createModel(self, model_input, n_outputs, first_session=True):
        
        if first_session != True:
            model = load_model('SI_ideal_model_fixed.hdf5')
            
            return model
        
        # Define Input Layer
        inputs = model_input
    
        # Define Densely Connected Layers
        conv = Dense(16, activation='relu')(inputs)
        conv = Dense(64, activation='relu')(conv)
        conv = Dense(16, activation='relu')(conv)
        conv = Reshape((conv.shape[1]*conv.shape[2]*conv.shape[3],))(conv)
        outputs = Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(conv)
    
        # Create Model
        model = Model(inputs, outputs)
        
        model.summary()
        
        return model
    
    
    # Train the Model
    def evaluateModel(self, x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val, num_classes, first_session=True):
        
        # Model Parameters
        verbose, epochs, batch_size, patience = 1, 100, 64, 10
    
        # Determine Input and Output Dimensions
        x = x_train[0].shape[0] # Number of MFCC rows
        y = x_train[0].shape[1] # Number of MFCC columns
        c = 1 # Number of channels
    
        # Create Model
        inputs = Input(shape=(x, y, c), name='input')
    
        model = self.createModel(model_input=inputs,
                                 n_outputs=num_classes,
                                 first_session=first_session)
    
        # Compile Model
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Callbacks
        es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           mode='min',
                           verbose=verbose,
                           patience=patience,
                           min_delta=0.0001) # Stop training at right time
    
        mc = ModelCheckpoint('SI_ideal_model_fixed.hdf5',
                             monitor='val_accuracy',
                             verbose=verbose,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='max') # Save best model after each epoch
    
        reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                      factor=0.2,
                                      patience=patience//2,
                                      min_lr=1e-3) # Reduce learning rate once learning stagnates
    
        # Evaluate Model
        model.fit(x_train, y=y_train, epochs=epochs,
                  callbacks=[es,mc,reduce_lr], batch_size=batch_size,
                  validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    
        accuracy = model.evaluate(x=x_train, y=y_train, 
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  verbose=verbose)
        
        # Load Best Model
        model = load_model('SI_ideal_model_fixed.hdf5')
    
        return (accuracy[1], model)
```

However, it appears that the `load_model` function is not working properly since the model achieved a validation accuracy of `0.56193` after the first training session but then only started with a validation accuracy of `0.2508` at the beginning of the second training session. (From what I have seen, the first epoch of the second training session should have a validation accuracy much closer to the that of the best model.)

Moreover, I then attempted to test the trained model on a set of unseen samples with `model.predict`, and it failed on all six, often with high probabilities, which leads me to believe that it was using minimally trained (or untrained) weights.

So, my question is could this be an issue from loading and saving the models using the `load_model` and `ModelCheckpoint` functions? If so, what is the best alternative method? If not, what are some good troubleshooting tips for improving the model's prediction functionality?

Comment: Could you please give more details on your dataset? For instance: if you are testing on image data, you might need to add `Conv2D `layer or if you are working a text data, you might need to add `LSTM` layer.

Comment: @AhmetTavli the dataset is comprised of .WAV audiofiles that have been digitized, normalized to a sample rate of 16 kHz, and converted into Mel frequency cepstral coefficients. So the CNN is analyzing NumPy arrays with of ```data_type=float64``` with a shape of ```(num_samples, 298, 12, 1)```.

Comment: Did you check this [article](https://medium.com/in-pursuit-of-artificial-intelligence/deep-learning-using-raw-audio-files-66d5e7bf4cca)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by training session. What I would do is first train for a few epochs epochs and note the validation accuracy. Then, load the model and use `evaluate()` to get the same accuracy. If it differs, then yes something is wrong with your loading. Here is what I would do:

```
def createModel(self, model_input, n_outputs):
        
        # Define Input Layer
        inputs = model_input
    
        # Define Densely Connected Layers
        conv = Dense(16, activation='relu')(inputs)
        conv2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(conv)
        conv3 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(conv2)
        conv4 = Reshape((conv.shape[1]*conv.shape[2]*conv.shape[3],))(conv3)
        outputs = Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(conv4)
    
        # Create Model
        model = Model(inputs, outputs)
        return model
    
    
    # Train the Model
    def evaluateModel(self, x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val, num_classes, first_session=True):
        
        # Model Parameters
        verbose, epochs, batch_size, patience = 1, 100, 64, 10
    
        # Determine Input and Output Dimensions
        x = x_train[0].shape[0] # Number of MFCC rows
        y = x_train[0].shape[1] # Number of MFCC columns
        c = 1 # Number of channels
    
        # Create Model
        inputs = Input(shape=(x, y, c), name='input')
    
        model = self.createModel(model_input=inputs,
                                 n_outputs=num_classes)
    
        # Compile Model
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Callbacks
        es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           mode='min',
                           verbose=verbose,
                           patience=patience,
                           min_delta=0.0001) # Stop training at right time
    
        mc = ModelCheckpoint('SI_ideal_model_fixed.h5',
                             monitor='val_accuracy',
                             verbose=verbose,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False) # Save best model after each epoch
    
        reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                      factor=0.2,
                                      patience=patience//2,
                                      min_lr=1e-3) # Reduce learning rate once learning stagnates
    
        # Evaluate Model
        model.fit(x_train, y=y_train, epochs=5,
                  callbacks=[es,mc,reduce_lr], batch_size=batch_size,
                  validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    
        model.evaluate(x=x_val, y=y_val, 
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  verbose=verbose)
        
        # Load Best Model
        model2 = load_model('SI_ideal_model_fixed.h5')
        model2.evaluate(x=x_val, y=y_val, 
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  verbose=verbose)
    
        return (accuracy[1], model)
```

The two evaluations should print the same thing really.
P.S. TF might change the order of your computations so I used different names to prevent that in the model e.g. conv1, conv2 ...)

Comment: thanks for the help. I applied the changes and the accuracy values printed the same, so it looks like ```load_model``` is working properly. However, renaming layers did not seem to fix the issue of decent validation accuracy/loss and then subpar performance in predicting unseen samples. Do you know of any good troubleshooting tips? (Or, is this something I should reopen as a separate question?)